# Calling an object dynamically in Matlab

Tags: oop, class, matlab

Say I have the following variable

```
myClassName = 'myClass';
```

And I want to call an instance of the myClass constructor function, ie.

```
myObject = myClass(arg1, arg2, ..., argn);
```

Let's say I want to call it using myClassName.

```
myObject = (myClassName)(arg1, arg2, ..., argn);      % something like that
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Got it. I found that this:

```
myFunc = str2func(myClassName);
myClass = myFunc(arg1, arg2, ..., argn);
```

Does the job.

Answer (score 0):

`eval` can also be used:

```
eval([myClassName '(arg1,arg2,arg3)']);
```

Comment: `str2func` is still much preferrable.

Answer (score 0):

Does the initial variable `myClassName` actually need to be a string?  I would implement this as:

```
myClassName = @myClass;
myObject = myClassName(arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

This is pretty similar to using the `str2func` call from your selfanswer, bit without the string operations which make some people (for example, me) feel wrong.